# which browsers currently support standard css border-radius

Tags: cross-browser, css

which browsers currently support standard css border-radius.

Is it now safe to omit the  -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius elements.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: This is a question more suited for Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All current browsers support the border-radius property, but for graceful degradation purposes it's good to include the vendor prefixes as well.

Here is a link with more detailed info:

http://caniuse.com/border-radius